# How to extend a typedef parameter in JSDOC?

Tags: javascript, typedef, extend, jsdoc, type-definition

Assuming you have the following code inside a ES6 class (documentation):

```
/**
 * @typedef Test~options
 * @type {object.<string>}
 * @property {array} elements - An array containing elements
 * @property {number} length - The array length
 */

/**
 * @param  {Test~options} opt - Option object
 */
test(opt){

}
```

Now I would like to document another function, let's name it `test2`. This function takes exactly the same `options` object, but needs another property `parent`.

How to document this without documenting redundant options? Redundant means:

```
/**
 * @typedef Test~options
 * @type {object.<string>}
 * @property {array} elements - An array containing elements
 * @property {number} length - The array length
 */

/**
 * @param  {Test~options} opt - Option object
 */
test(opt){

}


/**
 * @typedef Test~options2
 * @type {object.<string>}
 * @property {array} elements - An array containing elements
 * @property {number} length - The array length
 * @property {object} parent - The parent element
 */

/**
 * @param  {Test~options2} opt - Option object
 */
 test2(opt){

 }
```

Comment: Reference on GitHub: https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/1199

Answer (score 71):

I found this solution and this works very fine for me.
originally from [here](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/1199#issuecomment-457227207)

```
 /**
 * @typedef {Object} ChildType
 * @property {String} childProp
 *
 * @typedef {Base & ChildType} Child
 */
```

UPDATE: You can also use `@extends` to extend a jsdoc typedef.

```
/**
 * @typedef {object} ChildType
 * @extends Base
 * @property {string} childProp
 */
```

Second solution is better as `Base & ChildType` is not supported in plain jsdocs.

Comment: I can't really follow what the first solution is doing. This solution is very clear and concise

Comment: It's called an "[intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types)"

Comment: Cannot find name 'Base'.ts(2304)

Comment: Intersection Types are Typescript, and [are not supported](https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1285) in plain JSDoc.  Everybody keeps conflating official supported JSDoc syntax with Typescript's implementation of JSDoc parsing.  I suspect that this is because Typescript powers VSCode Intellisense, which has a pretty big market share, even among people who aren't actually writing Typescript.

Comment: Or just inline like this : ```@typedef {Base & {childProp: string}} Child```

Comment: @Coderer : Very true, but with JSDoc not being very well maintained (at least not expanding language features in years), I think TypeScript's flavor of JSDoc is really *the* standard to look to now, not only for reasons of adoption but also it being the only candidate supporting automated discovery of third party modules via `import()`. FWIW, more rationales on why we're planning to switch the default to typescript mode at https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-jsdoc/issues/834 even for plain JavaScript users (which tsc can process).

Comment: This & style syntax works in Visual Studio 2022 (probably older versions too), in a plain .js file. It probably works because Visual Studio uses Typescript to parse .js files.

Comment: I'd like to know if that last piece works for intellisense too. I tested it in VSCode and it insists I can't use `@extends` without it being linked to `@class` - it shows me an error _JSDoc '@extends' is not attached to a class._. In Webstorm I see no error, but it doesn't show me the base type properties either.

Answer (score 16):

Try it

```
/**
 * @typedef {object.<string>} Test~options
 * @property {array} elements - An array containing elements
 * @property {number} length - The array length
 */

/**
 * @param {Test~options} opt - Option object
 */
test(opt){

}

/**
 * @typedef {Test~options} Test~options2
 * @property {object} parent - The parent element
 */

/**
 * @param  {Test~options2} opt - Option object
 */
test2(opt){

}
```

Comment: This is the best solution so far, because it specifies the **type** of `Test~options2` as `Test~options`, linking to the latter. But this isn't ideal, because it doesn't repeat all the parameters of its "extended" type; it only lists the new params. JSDoc should work on better markup for this.

Comment: Just want to leave a note here in case it is useful - I think you aren't forced into inheritance here in the way it seems - you can have something like: @typedef {Mixin1 & Mixin2} MyMix (but note when you do that it doesnt seem to like additional properties added to the mix in my editor)

Comment: I was trying this method to extend properties of HTMLElement but didn't work.

Comment: Andrew, see my comment on the other answer -- this answer works without using any extended syntax that's unsupported in "plain" JSDoc, where the intersection operator (`&`) has no meaning.

Comment: Again, I'd like to know if this one works for intellisense too - VSCode doesn't show me any auto complete for the `parent` property, and if I write it as a property of an object typed as `/** @type { Test~options2 } */` the intellisense tells me it is not recognized as a known property of that type (it seems to work ok with Jetbrains intellisense, though).

Answer (score 12):

I don't like half-baked answers without a "full setup", so here is one:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Person
 * @property {string} name - The person's name
 * @property {number} age - The person's age
 */
/**
 * @typedef {Object} WizardProperties
 * @property {string[]} magicPowers
 * @typedef {Person & WizardProperties} Wizard
 */
/** @type {Wizard} */
export const wizard = {
    name: "Harry",
    age: 20,
    magicPowers: ["brroooomm"]
}
```

It also works across multiple files, but you have to use the `import('./person').Person` style:

- **person.mjs**:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Person
 * @property {string} name - The person's name
 * @property {number} age - The person's age
 */
```

- **wizard.mjs**:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} WizardProperties
 * @property {string[]} magicPowers
 * @typedef {import('./person').Person & WizardProperties} Wizard
 */
/** @type {Wizard} */
export const wizard = {
  name: "Harry",
  age: 20,
  magicPowers: ["brroooomm", "wheeeeeeeeeeeew"]
}
```