# How to document the return of a function, that is made from combining a spread objects with other properties?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, spread-syntax

I've got code that spreads the returned object, and adds in a new property

It looks like this :

```js
/**
 * it does the things
 * @param {Object} input object containing id and key
 * @param {Object.string} id unique id to associate with return value
 * @param {Object.string} key unique key used to get things
 * @returns {Object.<{???, id:string}>} the returned things and id.
 */
const doTheThings = ({id, key}) =>
  thingDoer(key).then(things => {
    ...things, // how do I document the properties of this
    id         // combining with this?
  })
```

I currently have `???` in the `@returns` part equal to `things: *`. but that makes it look like there will be a key called 'things' in the return, when there's not.

How do I document what `things` is? Does it change if `thingDoer` has a JSDoc of its own I can lean on? Preferably without involving typescript.

Comment: Sounds like a generic here. You take `T` and return it enriched. Does it *always* add the same properties (the `things`) or can they be different?

Comment: @VLAZ except JavaScript doesn't have generics. When you say "Does it always add..." do you mean does the function `thingDoer` always return the same `things`? Yes, it's always the same shape, but the values might change.

Comment: "*except JavaScript doesn't have generics*" but JSDoc has ;) Even if they aren't well documented. "*Yes, it's always the same shape, but the values might change.*" then perhaps a generic is an overkill. If it's always the same, maybe you just need [`@typedef`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html).

Answer (score 2):

The fact that it is using spread syntax is irrelevant. You document what the function *does* not necessarily how. So, it takes *some* object and (potentially) enriches it with more properties keeping the `id` in place.

```
/**
 * @typedef Thingamajig 
 * @type {object}
 * @property {number} foo - some number here
 * @property {string} bar - a string used for something
 */

/**
 * Transforms things.
 * @param {string} key - what to transform
 * @return {Promise<Thingamajig>} - transforms into this
 */
function thingDoer(key) { /* .... */ }

/**
 * it does the things
 * @param {Object} input - object containing id and key
 * @param {string} input.id - unique id to associate with return value
 * @param {string} input.key - unique key used to get things
 * @returns {Promise<Thingamajig & {id:string}>} the returned things and id.
 */
const doTheThings = ({id, key}) =>
  thingDoer(key).then(things => {
    ...things,
    id
  })
```

[See on the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?filetype=js#code/PQKhCgAIUgBAXAngBwKYBNUDNIBUAWAlgHYDmAhgLbkBWhpkUMCKqkA3gPYBGNqAxvAC+TOMgBOnNOKQdiAV0rdU4oZCydOkALSQAzp0psFSlZHwrUo2BKkrZ7PfHElSa7uXE7I5fc9eQ8noY6pxeBkbwRGRMwODgoBDQeOLkxHoa4pR6kFGuegB01sieVBxOLmRqANaoiN4A7vjk8LlazmkZYZTW4qjw8uLEHAAKkpSEwQA8BK5UtPQAfGq6HemZ2ZAk8O1EerHgWPLEgoScw3lkACKcKgAUtYgAlByQoJAFnwXQwJAiCWBRIRWuhbjkomxLqR9skbKVKBwAPK8ATCLbEZDyVq6Hh8QSQfjneDkEgBQjoHzECmPYrw8r+KrozHwArk7zHQgAR3kbDZOx8egM-EILTYDWB+EgfQGQ0gADdyAAbHm01IIxwMtxMrEFR7s4hcnmQPVBEL80j9XLRaG9fqDdKjcaTVAza3zOgMABkHHJAC4-JU3EJlla2NL7WbrTk0hTyUUfuBCekQZwCKhZmQcgBeSB3djkgA0xrqQheWcWUCtrhu90eTwKEOIdyh2cWHErkA+nxbBY7W3QldL8VBaYz0LzfsgACIAIxTouPf1TiyKxWcKdDzudhsWJt9PTyRWtcvtrdnqWoA9H1noADcW+AwAqrj7Z-3h5ZGk497ewBMyi8XQpwiYxFAA8xLCnV8t3fa8PHEH9H2fMhvCnXxkIYU0KUyfRDH6a0oPPGDLw-Aomhae9HzSRA+1LIA) - the file type has been set to JavaScript (found under **TS Options**), so this is purely a way to demonstrate how the JSDoc will be interpreted. Hover over functions and parameters to see what their types are.

The key thing here is using [`@typedef`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html) to declare the same object structure that `thingDoer` returns and `doTheThings` also uses. That way if it changes, you only change one place.

The `doTheThings` function then returns `Thingamajig & {id:string}` which is a `Thingamajig` with an added `id` property which is a string. An alternative is to create another typedef like `ThingamajigWithId` and document the property there. Depends on which tool consumes the JSDoc.

```
/**
 * @typedef ThingamajigWithId
 * @type {object}
 * @property {number} foo - some number here
 * @property {string} bar - a string used for something
 * @property {string} id - unique identifier.
 */
```

One interesting thing you can do with [an intersection (the `&`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) is to declare the type with an ID separately, then intersect the two. This way you can document it:

```
/**
 * @typedef Thingamajig 
 * @type {object}
 * @property {number} foo - some number here
 * @property {string} bar - a string used for something
 */

/**
 * @typedef WithId
 * @type {object}
 * @property {string} id - unique identifier
 */

/** ...
 * @returns {Promise<Thingamajig & WithId>} the returned things and id.
 */
```

[See on the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?filetype=js#code/PQKhCgAIUgBAXAngBwKYBNUDNIBUAWAlgHYDmAhgLbkBWhpkUMCKqkA3gPYBGNqAxvAC+TOMgBOnNOKQdiAV0rdU4oZCydOkALSQAzp0psFSlZHwrUo2BKkrZ7PfHElSa7uXE7I5fc9eQ8noY6pxeBkbwRGRMwODgoBDQcEhomDgA6oRRAJLo1qlsXLwCwta20g5OLmRqhOje8sSEAI7ybPWoxPCEWIQqsfGJorji5MR6GuKUepBRrnoAdOWeVBzVrmoA1qiI3gDu+OTwc1rO45NhlNbiqPDy4sQcAAqSlITBADwErlS09AA+NS6c4TKYzSAkeBnIh6QZYJqCQicJ7zMgAEU4KgAFDtEABKDiQUCQRZkxbQYCQEQJMCibKQdBY2ZRNho0hw5I2VaUDgAeRKgjqxGQ8hOuh4fEEkH4KPg5BIAXqPmIDTxKzGvMc-lqkJFYsWyt0TVa7UhDWhPj0Bn4hGObH22XwkFu90ekAAbuQADbtDVrbU1Nx60XwRZ4xrNNpsCNBEKW0h3ObRDk3O4PCYvN4fVDfFN-OgMABkkCyuXQQOTbFdGfjKdm4wa9WWlPAsomJyZBFQPzIswAvJBsex6gAaSB4oSE-sAqDJ1yYnF4-GLVnEbHsgcAjhzyCksmb0e781zqfxLsWXsc4f1ABckAARABGB-jvH3h8Wb3ezgPs97vdVwsddbj0eRvROGcdwAmCXVQMCIMNdAAG4AOAYANjIbwHxNaNzS6Ho+hUB9jxg0DwLDDROFQ4lgBMZQvF0B8ImMRQGPMSwSNggDyMQjxxBo9DMIYJjfGEwJggaKZ9EMO4Uy47i4IQsNDmOVD0PGRBjynIA)

Note that type intersections are not part of JSDoc itself. They are a TypeScript feature. Depending on which tool consumes the JSDoc it might or might not work. For example, Visual Studio Code likely will not complain, however, if you have a tool that constructs documentation from the annotations, it might not recognise the `&` as valid.

---

Also note that there is a long-standing feature to add this type of extension of objects in JSDoc itself:

[Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1199) from April 2016
Question on Stack Overflow that spawned it: [How to extend a typedef parameter in JSDOC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36737921)

Right now there does not seem to be a way to extend a typedef that satisfies all consumers of JSDoc. The only thing that seems to be *guaranteed* to work is to manually create a typedef which manually repeats all properties (which I showed above):

```
/**
 * @typedef ThingamajigWithId
 * @type {object}
 * @property {number} foo - some number here
 * @property {string} bar - a string used for something
 * @property {string} id - unique identifier.
 */
```

However, it does not change with the base typedef for `Thingamajig`, which makes it annoying to maintain. Here is a brief rundown of different things that might be supported

- Using an intersection works for anything that bases interpretation on TypeScript.
- There is also a plugin to extend JSDoc to recognise `&`.
- Some tools seem to support using `|` instead and would show `A | B` as having both properties from `A` and `B`, even though it should be an alternation.
- Some tools recognise

  ```
  /** 
   * @typedef {A, B} Combined 
   */
  ```
- Some tools recognise

  ```
  /** 
   * @typedef Combined 
   * @type {A, B}
   */
  ```

I could not find a technique that seems to work consistently everywhere.