# Let JSDoc infer return type of generic high-order function depending on optional parameter

Tags: javascript, generics, type-inference, jsdoc

Assuming the following function:

```js
/**
 * @template T
 * @template U
 * @param { T } item
 * @param { function(T): U } [mapper = t => t]
 * @returns { U }
 */
function map(item, mapper = t => t) {
  return mapper(item);
}
```

I would expect JSDoc to be able to infer the type of each of `one` and `two` in this snippet:

```js
const one = map('123', parseInt); // should be `number`
const two = map('123');           // should be `string`
```

Unfortunately, it appears that, when the optional `mapper` function isn't provided, the resulting type isn't inferred and `two` is just assumed to be `any`, as illustrated below:

[image: JSDoc hints]

I was hoping that documenting the `mapper` parameter of my `map` function as to be optional and **having a default value** (as documented [here](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html#:%7E:text=optional%20parameter%20foo-,with%20default%20value,-1.) would be enough.

What am I missing? Surely it must be possible!

Comment: Seems like it doesn't know the default is an identity function. There should be some way to say that `U = T` by default

Comment: @VLAZ Yep... I eventually figured precisely that myself and found a way to implement it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper implementation of the JSDoc type-inference for the `map` function is...

```js
/**
 * @template T
 * @template [U = T]
 * @param { T } item
 * @param { function(T): U } [mapper = t => t]
 * @returns { U }
 */
function map(item, mapper = t => t) {
  return mapper(item);
}
```

The sole difference is in the declaration of the return-type template `U`:

```js
/** @template U */
```

... needs to become:

```js
/** @template [U = T] */
```

This lets your type-inference system understand that the generic type `U`, when unable to be inferred, should default to being equivalent to `T`!

This seems to only be documented [in the TypeScript JSDoc reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#template). It does appear to function, as illustrated below:

[image: JSDoc hints (as expected)]

Comment: "*While this doesn't seem to be documented anywhere (?), it does appear to function, as illustrated below:*" just a warning - it *might* not be supported "officially". The `@template` is a bit weird anyway as it's not part of [the documentation](https://jsdoc.app/) - IIRC, it was a Closure compiler extension. The behaviour might differ between whatever is consuming the JSDoc. If you're using VSCode, it might recognise `[U = T]` but another tool might not. Or might interpret it differently.

Comment: @VLAZ I thought about this I did look for a "JSDoc playground" online but the first/only one is a TypeScript playground :)
I kinda suspect there might be a bit of TS mixed with the JSDoc in there, and I was about to leave a comment to my own answer to ask if anybody had any sources to demonstrate why it works.

Comment: @VLAZ You're right, `@template` isn't even documented/perhaps not technically part of JSDoc at all... ! It had never occurred to me. Thanks for your insight!

Comment: Yep. VSCode has a built-in way that it reads and uses JSDoc comments. The TS playground also uses some (if not all?) of the core of VSCode. Both TS and VSCode are Microsoft products. I've found [other stuff that's not widely supported everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69975890). BTW, TypeScript also has a guide for how it handles some JSDoc. [It includes `@template`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#template) and also mentions the default type parameter.

Comment: Also, I found the `@template` "origins" - [it's indeed Closure compiler](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler#template-t). I put "origins" in quotes because I'm not sure if Closure came up with it. I think they *documented* it, but not sure whether it's an official feature outside of that.

Comment: @VLAZ Woah, thank you!! Nice findings all around, but especially for the specification of a default for a type parameter in the TypeScript-powered parsing of the JSDoc-style typing. I don't regret asking the question, if only for your extra knowledge :) I'll have more insight into where to look/where it all came from in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: This is a *very good* question and an excellent self-answer. JSDoc is...a bit like occult knowledge in some cases. You may have to cross reference the Necronomicon against some Kabbalah texts to find out how to do something that should be mundane. And then you have to try to find whether it works for you, or you need to change the brand of chalk you use to draw your runes. It's good to have this knowledge out in the open, so we don't have to go seek out the writings of the mad Abdul Alhazred all the time. The poor guy was probably driven mad by the lack of good documentation.