# How to extend a typedef parameters in JSDOC?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I have a JSDoc comment of a typedef like below,

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} obj1
 * @property {boolean} a - Property 1
 * @property {boolean} b - Property 2
 */
```

I want to have a new typedef which includes the following properties as well:

```
* @property {boolean} c - Property 3
* @property {boolean} d - Property 4
```

How to add any additional properties to the object besides **a** and **b**?

In code, it's like this:

```js
const obj1 = {
  a: true,
  b: false
}

const obj2 = {
  a: true,
  b: false,
  c: true,
  d: false
}
```

As you can see **a** and **b** are shared, so I don't want to repeat defining them, they're exactly the same.

How to add properties to an existing definition?

in code, we can do something like:

```js
const obj2 = {
  ...obj1,
  c: true,
  d: false
}
```

Can we do something like the following jsDoc?

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} obj1
 * @property {boolean} a - Property 1
 * @property {boolean} b - Property 2
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} obj2
 * @property {...obj1}
 * @property {boolean} c - Property 3
 * @property {boolean} d - Property 4
 */
```

??

Comment: JS Merge objects https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: @JanPfeifer, no guys no, read the question well

Comment: maybe you are looking for the intersection type: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36737921/how-to-extend-a-typedef-parameter-in-jsdoc

Comment: @DiegoD, I think yes,.. give me a minute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is simple:

it's by using this syntax:

```js
/** 
 * @typedef {Obj1Props & Obj2Props} obj2
*/
```

## Full solution:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Obj1Props
 * @property {boolean} a - Property 1
 * @property {boolean} b - Property 2
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} Obj2Props
 * @property {boolean} c - Property 3
 * @property {boolean} d - Property 4
 */

/** 
 * @typedef {Obj1Props & Obj2Props} obj2
*/

/** @type {Obj1Props} */
const obj1 = {
  a: true,
  b: false
}

/** @type {obj2} */
const obj2 = {
  a: true,
  b: false,
  c: true,
  d: false
}
```